# SharePoint 2013 Workflow If Date Column is Blank

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I've read online that you can set a 2010 workflow to check for a blank date column in a list like this:

> If [date column] contains [1/1/0001]

*conditions etc...*

However in a 2013 workflow I don't see the "contains" operator to do something similar. Is it possible to do this in a 2013 workflow?

> If [date column] is blank

*conditions etc...*

The lowest date a SharePoint 2013 workflow allows me to enter in is between January, 01, 1900 - December 31, 8900. (blank isn't an option)

Comment: example from the web http://appdevonsharepoint.com/blanking-out-a-date-field-via-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Comment: Check also Three Methods at [Check if Date Field is NULL or Empty in SharePoint Designer Workflow](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/02/check-if-a-date-field-is-null-or-empty-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just remembered how I achieved this using workflow variables to check if the date field was blank.

Here is what my workflow logic ended up something like this:

`Set Variable: TempDateString to CurrentItemDateField`

`If Variable TempDateString contains 1/1/0001`

*send email, set date to today ect...*

This was a useful way to use the date field to show the users when an email was sent and it also acts as a flag so the email doesn't get sent more than once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Date less than 1/1/1900`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try many validations. For instance you could have,

```
Date *is less than* 2/1/0001
```

Or if you wish to stick with contains, you should try *index of*,

```
Find 1/1/2001 in Date (output variable to index)
```

...now if the value of index is valid, you know that the date is  *blank*.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column, data type date, name EmptyDate (or whatever name) and leave it blank, no default value. 
If checking for a date value in a workflow, then condition is, 
if YourDate > EmptyDate do something.
else YourDate is blank.
I'm guessing sharepoint internally sets column EmptyDate to 1/1/1900, just a guess. I create column EmptyDate in any and all of my lists/libraries that use a workflow date comparison.