# How to create timestamp workflow in sharepoint 2013

Tags: workflow, infopath

I have InfoPath form which has fields:

1. Quiz Title
2. Start Date
3. Due date
4. Quiz completed: check box

I want to add timestamp workflow to see how long did it take for one to finish the quiz. How do i create one?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you create one more date and time column...Quiz completed... And use calculated formula to check the difference between start date and completed date?

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes I can add more fields such as date and time. How do I create the calculated formula workflow. I have never done it before. I want to incorporate calculated formula workflow with send email workflow. I want to send completion email (I can add one more field called email to) and have the timestamp attached in the email? Can you please list down the process for me

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps as a solution for your requirements:

1. Add one more date & time field in your sharepoint list `Quiz completion Date`.
2. Add one calculated field to calculate the time taken to complete the quiz. Use formula something like this(you can check other formatting to show the time difference in 1st link given in sources below):

   `=IF(ISBLANK([Quiz completion Date])," ",TEXT([Quiz completion Date]-[Start Date],"d"))`
3. Add workflow on your list with triggering condition as `on item changed`(considering quiz completion date will be entered by editing list item).
4. In workflow at the starting check if the Quiz completion Date is empty or not.
5. If it is empty then complete the workflow. If it is not empty then add send an email action.

Sources:

1. [Calculated column formulae](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)#date-and-time-formulas).
2. [Calculate data in lists or libraries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calculate-data-in-lists-or-libraries-c5261743-667f-4833-bede-e516cef2a0e1).
3. [Check for empty date in SPD Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61115/check-for-empty-date-in-spd-workflow)
4. [SharePoint 2013 Workflow If Date Column is Blank](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183615/sharepoint-2013-workflow-if-date-column-is-blank?rq=1)

Comment: When I include the formula, it gives me technical error

Comment: While returning the calculated field, return as single line of text.... this option is given below formula.

Comment: try using updated formula, use display names of your fields in formula. I have tried this on my site and it is working as expected.

Comment: I added the error message to the question. I tried the formula ( I wrote the formula on the description field aswell just to show u what I have) It's in the image above. I keep getting the error on the image provided.