# Sharepoint Designer 2013 Workflow with two conditions including variable

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, date-time, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have two SharePoint list - One is funnel and other is decision register.
If certain condition is met in Funnel for that item, it will be moved to other list Decision Register.

I have following conditions to check in Funnel list -

1. If **Approval Status = CPO Approved** and **Decision Effective date is not blank** then move to Decision Register list.
2. If Approval Status = CPO Rejected then move to Decision Register List.

For first condition it is mandatory to have Decision effective date whereas for second when Rejected Decision Effective date is not applicable.

I tried with following code in SD 2013 but it is not working as desired. For first condition when date is empty and Approval Status is CPO approved, it is still moving to Decision Register.

```
Stage:Stage 1
Step: 1
    Set Variable: Decisiondate to Current Item:Decision Effective Date
    If Variable: Decisiondate is not empty value
    and Current Item:Approval Status equals CPO Approved
        Create item in M-Milestone Decision Register (Output to Variable: create3 )
        Delete item in Current Item
If Current Item:Approval Status equals CPO Rejected
    Create item in M-Milestone Decision Register (Output to Variable: create3 )
    Delete item in Current Item
```

Transition to stage
Go to End of Workflow

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the date column is blank or not in designer workflow you need to use below conditions:

```
If Variable Decisiondate contains 1/1/0001
```

**OR**

```
If Variable Decisiondate less than 2/1/0001
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint 2013 Workflow If Date Column is Blank](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183615/sharepoint-2013-workflow-if-date-column-is-blank)

**Update from Comments**:

For your case, try using the condition as: `If Variable Decisiondate greather than 1/1/0001`

**Note**: Your variable data type should be set as Date and not string.

Comment: HI Ganesh, I tried this but this is not working in a sense that it is not at all moving now.

Comment: For your case, try using the condition as: `If Variable Decisiondate greather than 1/1/0001`.

Comment: There is no option for greater than in SD with Variable. Following options are available for operator - contains, not equals, is empty, is not empty, begins with, ends with, doesnot end with, does not begins with, equals, matches regular expression. I dont see any option for less than and greater than.

Comment: I think less than and greater than option will be available directly to date column or date variable. it will not be available for string variables. So either try creating a date variable or rewrite your conditions like: `If Variable Decisiondate contains 1/1/0001` **Else** `If Current Item:Approval Status equals CPO Approved` --> write your code to create item in nested **IF**.

Comment: Ganesh, I found the issue. Earlier I set this variable as string so that it can be compared as not empty. Now instead of Variable, I used directly Decision effective date compared with 1/1/2000. It worked. thanks.

Comment: Great,  glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.